# Reported problem in the Javascript of my website

Tags: javascript, html

My website has a simple slide carousel which works correctly, but the SEOptimer evaluation report says:

> “Cannot read property 'className' of undefined at showSlides (http://www.abacus-arts.org.uk/:78:8) ”

Line 78 is near the end below and says: `dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";`

Can I safely ignore the SEOptimer problem report, or can you help me to fix it?

```html
<div>
<!-- code for slides 1 to 4 removed, below are slides 5 and 6 in the carousell -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="picnumber"> 5 / 6</div> <img src="Pic-5-DM.jpg" alt="Pic5" style="width:100%";> 
     <div class="pictitle"> Breakout room LHS view                      </div> </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="picnumber"> 6 / 6</div> <img src="Pic-6-GW.jpg" alt="Pic6" style="width:100%";> 
     <div class="pictitle"> Street view of entrance  </div> </div>
 <!-- Back and forward buttons jump to the Java Script lower down -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"> &lt;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">  &gt;</a>
</div>
 <!-- from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp -->
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
 function plusSlides(n)   {   showSlides(slideIndex += n); }
 function currentSlide(n) {   showSlides(slideIndex = n);  }
 function showSlides(n)   {   var i;
   var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
//   var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
//   var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
   if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1                }
   if (n < 1)             {slideIndex = slides.length    }
   for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { slides[i].style.display = "none";  }
//   for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++)  
//   { dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");  }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
//   dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
//  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;  
 }
</script>
```

UPDATE. Solved by removing the lines for unused variables as shown //.

Comment: Does the carousel not work, or are you asking us to debug the _scanner_?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error also occurs if you open the site in your browser and check the developer tools. And yes you should fix that.

Comment: My first guess would be that `dots[slideIndex - 1]` is attempting to index a value outside of the `dots` array.

Comment: It also appears that there aren't any elements that match the `.demo` selector.

Comment: @phuzi    demo is not mentioned anywhere else in the css or html. will deleting it solve the problem?

Comment: @t.niese    the carousel at my website www.abacus-arts.org.uk works fine and using Chrome/inspect shows no issues that I can see [ may be my lack of knowledge in using the tool ]

Comment: @isherwood Yes the carousel works fine as expected, See my website www.abacus-arts.org.uk

Comment: `dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");` results in an empty collection because there aren't any elements with the `demo` class. This means that any index value, even `dots[0]` will result in `undefined`. You need to figure out what `dots` should be or if you even need it but it is used in a number of places.

Answer (score 0):

@phuzi Thank you all for encouraging me to search for unused variables, I found in evolving the HTML I has stopped using "demo, dots and captiontext" and the problem went away when these code lines were excluded.
Many thanks. Graeme.

Answer (score -2):

```
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

there is null, it mean - i dont find any classes with name "demo"
check html part code

Comment: Responding to the comments.

Comment: This should be a comment and does not answer the question.